# Combine two XPath expressions with a common prefix path?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, lxml

I have this XPath.

```
//div[@class = 'section methods']/h2 | //div[@class = 'section methods']/div[@class = 'subsection']
```

Because they share a common prefix path, I want to consolidate them to something like the following.

```
//div[@class = 'section methods']/(h2 | div[@class = 'subsection'])
```

But `lxml` in python gives error. Is there a way to consolidate them properly?

Comment: can you post html source or url link ?

Comment: The question is not related to a specific URL or HTML code. If you must have an example, you can just create one using both the h2 and div tags in the xpath in the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two XPaths,

```
//div[@class = 'section methods']/h2
//div[@class = 'section methods']/div[@class = 'subsection']
```

can be combined into this single XPath:

```
//div[@class = 'section methods']/*[self::h2 or self::div[@class = 'subsection']]
```